# Filter data by last 3 months and by ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas data-frame where 2 columns are there,

```
    ID   Month

    1    Jan-18
    1    Dec-17
    1    Feb-18
    1    Nov-17
    1    Oct-17
    1    Sep-17
    2    Jan-18
    2    Dec-17
    2    Feb-18
    2    Nov-17
    2    Oct-17
    2    Mar-18
```

I want to get latest 3 months data by ID

expected output,

```
    ID   Month

    1    Dec-17
    1    Jan-18
    1    Feb-18

    2    Jan-18
    2    Feb-18
    2    Mar-18
```

I tried filtered techniques from pandas but I failed to apply multiple condition where second condition is by latest months.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) first, sorting by both columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), convert `Month` column back to original format by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and call [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format='%b-%y')
df1 = (df.sort_values(['ID','Month'])
         .assign(Month=df['Month'].dt.strftime('%b-%y'))
         .groupby('ID')
         .tail(3))
print (df1)
    ID   Month
1    1  Dec-17
0    1  Jan-18
2    1  Feb-18
6    2  Jan-18
8    2  Feb-18
11   2  Mar-18
```

Another solution with month periods:

```
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format='%b-%y').dt.to_period('m')
df1 = (df.sort_values(['ID','Month'])
         .groupby('ID')
         .tail(3))
print (df1)
    ID    Month
1    1  2017-12
0    1  2018-01
2    1  2018-02
6    2  2018-01
8    2  2018-02
11   2  2018-03
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. solution is working perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more help needed. How to get the remaining data , I mean the reverse condition.

Comment: @Ajayjadhav - If there is default index use `df2 = df[~df.index.isin(df1.index)]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt help

Answer (score 0):

Option without the `assign()`

```
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format='%b-%y')
df2=df.sort_values(by=['ID','Month']).groupby('ID').tail(3)
df2['Month'] = df['Month'].dt.strftime('%b-%y')
print(df2)
```